# Security of Text Hashing with NodeJS Server

Tags: node.js, security, encryption

I have a NodeJS server in which I need to hash passwords from clients.  As NodeJS apps are not compiled, would it be substantially more secure for me to write the hashing process in a language from which I can generate a binary that handles that process to be called from my NodeJS app, or if the server is compromised would the perpetrator be able to reverse engineer the binary handling the hashing process virtually as easily as reading it from the JS of my NodeJS app?

Comment: Passwords should be *hashed* not encrypted, this greatly reduces the security issue by ensuring the the passwords don't actually exist at rest anywhere on the backend.

Comment: Thank you for the note, Alex. That is the process I was intending to express in my question.  I have updated my question thusly.

Comment: Don't write your own hashing process, use a SHA2 or 3 implementation.  You salt and hash the password so if someone grabs your database they can't reverse engineer the actual credentials. Trying to hide the algorithm doesn't provide security -- salting and hashing your passwords using a proven algorithm of sufficient strength is a more secure approach.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashing - as opposed to encryption - is a one-way process. It's easy to get a hash from the plain text but it's nearly impossible to do the reverse, unless you happen to guess what was the hashed text.

For that reason you don't need to keep your hashing algorithm secret. You shouldn't really, because all of the strong ones are public and it is really hard to invent your own.

For example, the SHA-256 algorithm is public. But try guessing what I just hashed to:

```
07123e1f482356c415f684407a3b8723e10b2cbbc0b8fcd6282c49d37c9c1abc
```

You should be able to guess it if you try (**please comment if you can guess it!**) because my text was very simple on purpose and I used a fast hashing function on purpose - to make it clear that you need to keep few things in mind:

1. your hashing algorithm needs to be strong
2. your passwords must be hard to guess even for strong algorithms
3. your hashing function should be as slow as possible (this may sound like a strange requirement for software - see below for more info)

SHA-1 or SHA-2 are fast and as such are not sufficient to make the passwords safe, even with a random salt. But you can use hashing algorithms with arbitrarily complex computation (e.g. bcrypt) to make guessing slower but it will always be possible.

Also, use random salts to make the rainbow tables impossible to use.

You want to use a slow, CPU-intensive algorithms to make the guessing as slow as possible while still making the normal operation possible. E.g. bcrypt (which doen't use SHA-1 or SHA-2 but Blowfish) in addition to the salt has a cost parameter that you can use to make the resulting function as costly as you want, making the guessing slower to the point of making it pointless. E.g. if you can make one iteration last 100ms then it is still not very long to wait for password verification by real users but it is much to slow to guess the password by the attacker quickly - 10 tries per second is less than a million per day. It's a number similar to how many SHA-256 hashes you can compute in a single second.

For more info see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2

Thanks to **zaph** and **LukePark** for the comments on how to improve this answer.

**I am still waiting** for anyone to **guess my hashed message** to prove my point of SHA-1 being insufficient for hashing passwords. **Hint:** It is quite short.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.

Comment: A paragraph about PBKDF2/bcrypt and why a single iteration of SHA2 is not sufficient would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: One reason why SHA-256 with a salt is not sufficient is a laptop (mine) can execute 750,000 per second, this would be applied to a list of 10,000,000 passwords sorted by frequency of usage Then there are special programs that fuzz those. Unless it is spear-fishing an attacker will probably be satisfied with 90% of the passwords cracked. So by lengthening the computer time from <2us to >100ms it takes the attacker 50,000 times as long. It is all about making increasing the work factor of an attacker.

Comment: @zaph That was actually what I originally meant by "You can use hashes with arbitrarily complex computation" but it may have been not clear anough. Thanks for pointing it out. I updated my answer.

Comment: @LukePark When I wrote "You can use hashes with arbitrarily complex computation" I actually meant algorithms like bcrypt but thanks for pointing it out because it was not clear enough. I updated my answer.

Comment: Close, it is the iterations of ~100ms that are important and bcrypt does not use SHA, it uses Blowfish.

Comment: @zaph Yes I know it uses Blowfish. I didn't say that bcrypt uses SHA but you're right, it's better to make it explicit. I updated my answer. Let me know if you think it could be improved further. Thanks.

Comment: There are two main types of password attacks: all the users of a site and a specific user. When an entire site is attacked it is not necessary to find all the passwords, just a lot. Then the passwords are addd to user records and this entire set of user information is sold on the dark net. Making the computation costly in time helps against this type of attack. Attacking a specific user is only necessary on a Spear Phishing like attack and then if the password is not in the 10M list and fuzzing still does not work a more expensive complete brute force attack can be mounted.